# Flask отказаться от jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Добрый день,
Можно ли убрать зависимость flask от jinja2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Из документации:

> Flask leverages Jinja2 as template engine. You are obviously free to use a different template engine, but you still have to install Jinja2 to run Flask itself.

Т.е. вы можете спокойно использовать для своих шаблонов любой другой шаблонизатор, но, Jinja2 все равно придется устанавливать, т.к. он является зависимостью для Flask.

К тому же, если вы используете какие-либо сторонние модули Flask, то они скорее всего также используют Jinja2 и будут проблемы несовместимости.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что нет.

Во-первых, в описании чётко сказано "A microframework based on Werkzeug, Jinja2 and good intentions".

Во-вторых, из ключей для сборки только doc, examples и test.

А в чём проблема? Какие причины не поставить Jinja2?